# How to add destructor to the db handle returned from DBI::connect?

Tags: perl, dbi

The package has a wrapper for DBI->connect:

```
Package MyPackage;
our $dbh;
sub connect {
    $dbh = DBI->connect(...)
    return $dbh;
}

sub disconnect {
    $dbh->disconnect;
    #some other things...
}
In the client program:
{
    my $dbh = MyPackage->connect(...)
}
```

MyPackage is just a function package, it is not a class.
but now I want to use RAII, when leaving the scope where the client calls MyPackage->connect,disconnect is called.
DESTROY function can not be called because we don't return an object of MyPackage. 
I don't want to change the interface and client codes, such as add new method, so I think maybe there is a way to inherit from DB handle and overrides its DESTROY method of it.In the DESTROY method, it can call MyPackage->disconnect.

Is it doable or could someone help think out any other good solutions?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this if you like.

```
Package MyPackage;
use base 'DBI::db';
sub connect {
    my $dbh = DBI->connect(...)
    bless $dbh => 'MyPackage';
    return $dbh;
}

sub DESTROY {
    my ($dbh) = @_;
    $dbh->disconnect;
    #some other things...
}
```

The  client program can still call your `connect` subroutine just as before. When the instance goes out of scope, the DESTROY method is called and is handled by your code.  Other database handle methods are handled by DBI::db, just as they were before.